# Is this a printf()/pthread bug, or am I missing something?

Tags: c, pthreads, printf, mutex

I recently endeavoured to learn about multiple threading, and ran into the following unexpected - to me, at least - behaviour: printf just will not print more than a line at once when called in the very simple following code:

```
    pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    char buffer[2];

    void * thread_routine(void * args){
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
      printf("test %s\n test\n", buffer);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      return(NULL);
    }

    int main(void){
      pthread_t thread;
      pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_routine, NULL);
      sleep(1);
      buffer[0] = 'c';
      buffer[1] = '\0';
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      sleep(10);
      return(0);
    }
```

The output is

```
    test c
```

(wait for 10 seconds and)

```
    test prompt$]
```

What is wrong with this code? How come I can't get printf to print two lines at once? Please note that blocking stdout with flockfile and unlocking with funlockfile does nothing to improve the situation.

Comment: You haven't declared `buffer` as `volatile`, which won't be helping.

Comment: Can you try running `fflush(stdout);` after each call to `printf()` and see if that changes things?

Comment: If you included the `#include`s required to compile this it would be an excellently asked question

Comment: @undur_gongor: I've taken the liberty to reinstate the lack of newline in the second part of the output, since I think it's key to this question (see my answer below).

Comment: @oli-charlesworth, there's no need for `volatile` here. Using proper locking functions is enough. Once a function has been called, the compiler must assume `buf` may have changed, and will read it again after waking up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your program printed `test prompt$]` at the end as you say, this means that the version that you executed didn't have the second newline in `"test %s\n test\n"`.

Newlines are important, since this is when the output gets flushed to the screen. See [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin) for an explanation and recommendations.

Try re-compiling and re-running the exact code from your question, and I bet it'll work as expected (it certainly does on my box).

Comment: Actually, the *exact code* from his question won't compile. It is missing at least one `#include`.

Comment: Thak you much. Didn't know about that and expected the string to be printed immediately. Thank you.